# Video.js - does not subscribe to the live stream

Tags: video.js

Does anyone know if there is an option to tell Video.js to subscribe to a live rtmp stream?  There is an option for this in flowplayer and jwplayer. I'm using Edgecast for a CDN and they require this option.

from flowplayer subscribe:

> Set to true to make the plugin 'subscribe' to the stream. Needed for RTMP live streams from Akamai, Limelight and other CDNs which may require the FCSubscribe command.

If I use jwplayer on the same computer to play the stream, Video.js starts to play.  When I stop the jwplayer the Video.js player stops.

Thanks
Austin

Answer (score 0):

I compiled [video-js-swf](https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf) manually and modified the [RTMPVideoProvider](https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf/blob/6d262f5c9b6f1d919220201f0c1f0bc113a2271a/src/com/videojs/providers/RTMPVideoProvider.as) implementation to call FCSubscribe during the NetStream initialization.

```
_nc.call("FCSubscribe", null, _src.streamURL);
```

Simply requesting the live stream from EdgeCast, Akamai and other CDN is not sufficient. We must tell the edge server (the CDN node) to subscribe and pull the stream from its origin.

Then I implemented onFCSubscribe that was a #NOOP to start the stream

```
public function onFCSubscribe(pInfo:Object):void {
  if (pInfo.code == "NetStream.Play.Start") {
    _ns.play(_src.streamURL);
    _videoReference.attachNetStream(_ns);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response heymatty.  Did you remove the original `_ns.play...` and `_videoReference...` function calls and replace them with the `_nc.call...` call?  Or add `_nc.call..` some other location.